# How to transform DataFrame per one column to create two new columns in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe "x", In which their are two columns "x1" and "x2"

```
x1(status)    x2  
kv,true       45
bm,true       65
mp,true       75
kv,null       450
bm,null       550
mp,null       650
```

I want to convert this dataframe into a format in which data is filtered according to its status and value

```
x1  true  null
kv   45    450
bm   65    550
mp   75    650
```

Is there a way to do this,
I am using pyspark datadrame

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way. First split the first column by `,` using [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) function, then split this dataframe into two dataframes (using `where` twice) and simply join this new dataframes on first column..

In Spark API for Scala it'd be as follows:

```
val x1status = Seq(
  ("kv,true",45),
  ("bm,true",65),
  ("mp,true",75),
  ("kv,null",450),
  ("bm,null",550),
  ("mp,null",650)).toDF("x1", "x2")

val x1 = x1status
  .withColumn("split", split('x1, ","))
  .withColumn("x1", 'split getItem 0)
  .withColumn("status", 'split getItem 1)
  .drop("split")

scala> x1.show
+---+---+------+
| x1| x2|status|
+---+---+------+
| kv| 45|  true|
| bm| 65|  true|
| mp| 75|  true|
| kv|450|  null|
| bm|550|  null|
| mp|650|  null|
+---+---+------+

val trueDF = x1.where('status === "true").withColumnRenamed("x2", "true")
val nullDF = x1.where('status === "null").withColumnRenamed("x2", "null")

val result = trueDF.join(nullDF, "x1").drop("status")

scala> result.show
+---+----+----+
| x1|true|null|
+---+----+----+
| kv|  45| 450|
| bm|  65| 550|
| mp|  75| 650|
+---+----+----+
```