# pyspark make two columns from a list in one column

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my first row of data:

```
Row(params=['id=407439', 'a=something', 'b=something_else', 'c=anything', 'd='])
```

I need two columns with values of **a** and **b**

```
Row(a='a=something', b='b=something_else')
```

or

```
Row(a='something', b='something_else')
```

I found such answer:
[How to transform DataFrame per one column to create two new columns in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40671827/how-to-transform-dataframe-per-one-column-to-create-two-new-columns-in-pyspark) But it doesn't say how to choose an element by some string pattern instead of an index.

I don't know if it matters, but I got my first list row with:

```
some_data.withColumn('params', split(string, '&'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
 some_data.withColumn('a', col('params').startswith('a='))
```

Answer (score 0):

After all this worked for me (but perhaps the other solution is better):

```
def get_param(string): #whole not splitted string
try:
    return dict(item.split('=') for item in string.split('&'))['a']
except:
    return string


from pyspark.sql.types import *
get_param_udf = udf(get_param, StringType())

new_data = some_data.withColumn('a', get_param_udf('string'))
```

And the same done for 'b'